# Why isn't Tailwind applying styles to my HTML?

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

Tailwind is not applying styles to my HTML. The "hello world" font has changed so Tailwind has been installed, but no style is being applied.

**Index.html:**

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link href = "/css/tailwind.css" rel ="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body class="bg-green-400">
        <h1 class="text-3xl font-bold underline">
            Hello world!
          </h1>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**Tailwind.css:**

```css
    @tailwind base;
    @tailwind components;
    @tailwind utilities;
```

**package.json:**

```json
    {
      "name": "islanderoutdoors",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "description": "",
      "main": "index.js",
      "dependencies": {
        "acorn": "^7.4.1",
        "acorn-node": "^1.8.2",
        "acorn-walk": "^7.2.0",
        "ansi-styles": "^4.3.0",
        "anymatch": "^3.1.2",
        "arg": "^5.0.1",
        "binary-extensions": "^2.2.0",
        "braces": "^3.0.2",
        "browserslist": "^4.19.1",
        "callsites": "^3.1.0",
        "camelcase-css": "^2.0.1",
        "caniuse-lite": "^1.0.30001300",
        "chalk": "^4.1.2",
        "chokidar": "^3.5.2",
        "color-convert": "^2.0.1",
        "color-name": "^1.1.4",
        "cosmiconfig": "^7.0.1",
        "cssesc": "^3.0.0",
        "defined": "^1.0.0",
        "detective": "^5.2.0",
        "didyoumean": "^1.2.2",
        "dlv": "^1.1.3",
        "electron-to-chromium": "^1.4.46",
        "error-ex": "^1.3.2",
        "escalade": "^3.1.1",
        "escape-string-regexp": "^1.0.5",
        "fast-glob": "^3.2.11",
        "fastq": "^1.13.0",
        "fill-range": "^7.0.1",
        "fraction.js": "^4.1.2",
        "fsevents": "^2.3.2",
        "function-bind": "^1.1.1",
        "glob-parent": "^6.0.2",
        "has": "^1.0.3",
        "has-flag": "^4.0.0",
        "import-fresh": "^3.3.0",
        "is-arrayish": "^0.2.1",
        "is-binary-path": "^2.1.0",
        "is-core-module": "^2.8.1",
        "is-extglob": "^2.1.1",
        "is-glob": "^4.0.3",
        "is-number": "^7.0.0",
        "js-tokens": "^4.0.0",
        "json-parse-even-better-errors": "^2.3.1",
        "lilconfig": "^2.0.4",
        "lines-and-columns": "^1.2.4",
        "merge2": "^1.4.1",
        "micromatch": "^4.0.4",
        "minimist": "^1.2.5",
        "nanoid": "^3.2.0",
        "node-releases": "^2.0.1",
        "normalize-path": "^3.0.0",
        "normalize-range": "^0.1.2",
        "object-hash": "^2.2.0",
        "parent-module": "^1.0.1",
        "parse-json": "^5.2.0",
        "path-parse": "^1.0.7",
        "path-type": "^4.0.0",
        "picocolors": "^1.0.0",
        "picomatch": "^2.3.1",
        "postcss-js": "^4.0.0",
        "postcss-load-config": "^3.1.1",
        "postcss-nested": "^5.0.6",
        "postcss-selector-parser": "^6.0.8",
        "postcss-value-parser": "^4.2.0",
        "queue-microtask": "^1.2.3",
        "quick-lru": "^5.1.1",
        "readdirp": "^3.6.0",
        "resolve": "^1.21.0",
        "resolve-from": "^4.0.0",
        "reusify": "^1.0.4",
        "run-parallel": "^1.2.0",
        "source-map-js": "^1.0.1",
        "supports-color": "^7.2.0",
        "supports-preserve-symlinks-flag": "^1.0.0",
        "to-regex-range": "^5.0.1",
        "util-deprecate": "^1.0.2",
        "xtend": "^4.0.2",
        "yaml": "^1.10.2"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "autoprefixer": "^10.4.2",
        "postcss": "^8.4.5",
        "tailwindcss": "^3.0.15",
        "vite": "^2.7.12"
      },
      "scripts": {
        "dev": "vite"
      },
      "keywords": [],
      "author": "",
      "license": "ISC"
    }
```

Comment: In your tailwind config file make sure your html file path is addressed in the content array. In my case I changed it from `content: ["./src/**/*.{html,js}"]` to `content: ["./{html,js}"]` then it worked. **Note:** *Both my tailwind.config.js and index.html files were in the same folder*

Answer (score 1):

You do not specify the input file (tailwind.css) as your stylesheet, you have to build the stylesheet with `npx tailwindcss -i ./src/tailwind.css -o ./dist/output.css --watch`. The `--watch` flag will rebuild your CSS when you save.
The destination and name of the output is up to you.

The HTML:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link href = "/dist/output.css" rel ="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body class="bg-green-400">
        <h1 class="text-3xl font-bold underline">
            Hello world!
          </h1>
    </body>
    </html>
```

[Docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation)

Comment: hi I have tried this and nothing has changed

Comment: @SVJ99
I am pretty sure you are making a mistake somewhere. This is a quite common mistake with tailwind. Go through the docs again, and check your code etc.
The thing is, if you would just save "all the tailwind CSS", you would end up with an insanely large CSS file.

Answer (score 1):

My issue was being caused by needing to run the build command from the same location as the config file.

```
npx tailwindcss -i ./src/input.css -o ./dist/output.css --watch
```

More detail -

I did not realise that the above tailwind command was not a GLOBAL command i.e. if your config file is in the root of your file system, but your css files are in the assets directory, you cannot run the build command from the assets directory, it needs to run from the root (or were ever the tailwind.config file is).

So:

in dir `assets/css/`

running `npx tailwindcss -i input.css -o output.css --watch` (where the tailwind css file is and output should be generated)

generates errors:

```
warn - The `content` option in your Tailwind CSS configuration is missing or empty.
warn - Configure your content sources or your generated CSS will be missing styles.
warn - https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration
```

From the location of the tailwind.config file i.e.
in dir `./` or `root`

running:

```
npx tailwindcss -i ./public_html/ASSETS/CSS/input.css -o ./public_html/ASSETS/CSS/output.css --watch
```

Then works.

This might be way to much info, but will help if you have moved your files around and are getting errors as a result.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, my content configuration was not correct the right source files was not correctly matched

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#classes-arent-generated

Answer (score -2):

try running the following command:

npm install -D tailwindcss postcss autoprefixer

npx tailwindcss init -p

and then proceed with your task as usual and see it it works

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).